# Comparing RapidMiner models with x-validation

Tags: neural-network, linear-regression, cross-validation, rapidminer

I am working in some forecasting models with RapidMiner and need some orientation to interpret the outputs and select the best among them. I am following some tutorials to check their accuracy with x-validation, and I am getting results like:

```
root_mean_squared_error: 1.613 +/- 0.374 (mikro: 1.651 +/- 0.000)
squared_error: 3.843 +/- 1.632 (mikro: 3.832 +/- 5.398)
```

for regression, and:

```
root_mean_squared_error: 1.917 +/- 0.410 (mikro: 1.958 +/- 0.000)
squared_error: 3.843 +/- 1.632 (mikro: 3.832 +/- 5.398)
```

for the neural nets. Which one would be the best? Why? Is there an straightforward way to get the 'r' value? Thanks !!

Comment: Smaller RMSE is better (so linear regression). Smaller error usually is better, but might be a symptom of overfitting. The good news: with linear regression it is almost impossible to overfit.

Comment: Great, thanks! so if the RMSE is 1.613, +/- 0.374 is the std dev? And what is Mikro? Cheers